# snapshots in Jest missing html

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am working on a react app where I created three new components. I use React testing library and Jest. Before this has worked just fine, but my new components does not seem to render any html text to the snapshots, even though the tests pass. I have written a couple of Jest snapshot tests before and tried doing the same thing to validate that the UI did correctly react to input.

I created three new components. they all have this issue of the snapshots not containing HTML.

creating a snapshot and doing expect(fragment).toMatchSnapshot() passes. However the snapshot is almost empty.
An example output is here;
// Jest Snapshot v1, **link_to_docs**

exports[`FunctionDescription TestStatement`] = `[Function]`;

So instead of `[Function]` I am supposed to have a HTML tree.

I have tried removing my **snapshot** folder and regenerating the .snap files, but they end up the same way.

test looks like this;

```
describe('ProsenttrekkSkattetrekk', () => {
  it('Rendrer korrekt', () => {
    const { asFragment } = renderWithTranslations(
      <ProsenttrekkSkattetrekk
        oppdaterInntektsInfo={jest.fn()}
        oppdaterTypeTrekk={jest.fn()}
        skattetrekk={{ prosent: undefined, type: 'prosenttrekk' }}
        prosenttrekkBelop={10}
      />
    );

    expect(asFragment).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The renderWithRouterAndTranslations method basically corrects URL segments and the returns the component wrapped in router in render, and has been used several times by us without this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

->    expect(asFragment).toMatchSnapshot(); asFragment is a function. Doing asFragment() resolves the missing html in the snapshot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).